# Connecting to Private Internet Access server using OpenVPN and Ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: server, 16.04, vpn, openvpn

Can someone please give me a guide to setup a vpn connection (that connects on startup) using openvpn and ubuntu 16.04 server. all the guides on the internet are wrong, outdated, or just don't work. i have an account with private internet access and i just want to setup a connection. something i feel should be very simple but i lack the experience needed as this is my first server and I'm still learning.

Answer (score 3):

Start by downloading this: https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/openvpn/openvpn.zip and extract it somewhere.

That archive contains 3 important files: `ca.crt`, `crl.pem` and `YourServer.ovpn` (e.g. `Germany.ovpn`), copy those to `/etc/openvpn/`. Rename the `.ovpn` file to `.conf` and add a line `auth-user-pass secrets` Create a new file `/etc/openvpn/secrets` with your PIA username on the first and your password on the second line, like this:

```
p1234567
MyPIAPassword
```

For security reasons you should `chmod 600` that.

See if your connection works: `systemctl start openvpn@YourServer` (e.g. `systemctl start openvpn@Germany`. Debug as necessary: `tail -f /var/log/syslog|grep ovpn` and `systemctl status openvpn@YourServer`

If it works, make it run on startup by editing `/etc/default/openvpn` and uncommenting the line that says `AUTOSTART="all"`

Comment: My SSH connection dropped as soon as i started the openvpn service, and I couldn't reconnect to my server (Ubuntu EC2), so I had to restore it from an AMI.